# How can I compress an .eps image (created in Photoshop) for a LaTeX document without sacrificing quality?

Tags: image, latex, photoshop, eps

I looked for similar questions and this does not quite seem to be a duplicate.  I have written a paper for a math journal.  The paper has 4 figures, and is typeset using LaTeX.  For some reason, the journal wants the images in .eps format.  3 out of the 4 images are quite large.  I created those three using Photoshop.  The largest is about 152MB.  The journal wants me to upload the .tex files and the .eps files separately.  When I tried to upload a 57MB .eps file, there was no response from the journal's Website for at least an hour and a half.  I sent an e-mail to the person from the journal tasked with fielding questions from people like me who have trouble uploading files.

By the way, the journal's automated uploading process only accepts a dozen or so file types, and zip files are not one of them.  The paper has been accepted and I am trying to upload a final version.

In the meantime, if I have to compress the .eps images somehow, can anyone recommend a good way to do it?  Again, they will be used by LaTeX.  I don't know exactly what process the journal uses to compile, or if it matters- I have to upload the .tex file and the .eps files and they compile everything.  Of course, I don't want to lose quality (does anybody?).  The 152MB file is fairly complicated, with circular arcs, line segments, shaded regions bounded by circular arcs, and Greek and Roman characters.  I saved it in Photoshop using an option called something like "save as Photoshop .EPS", which seems to give you a regular .eps file (I have compiled the LaTeX file successfully).

Comment: Why not just compress the file after the fact (e.g., as a zip)? You could also try using something like GhostScript to convert another file format into EPS and see if that yields a reduction in file size.

Comment: @Thomas : Thanks, but the journal's uploading process only permits a certain number of types of files (there are a dozen or so) and zip files are not one of them.  I think this is so the journal can automatically compile one's LaTeX file along with its images without human intervention.  Regarding your second suggestion, I can experiment, but do you have any suggestions what format to save the file as using Photoshop?

Comment: Well, save it as some kind of raster (PNG probably if you're using LaTeX) then see what happens. If this is just for initial review submission, the lower-resolution image should be fine; then if it's accepted, you can get the full-resolution version put in later.

Comment: "save as Photoshop .EPS"'s default is `ASCII85` encoding, is `JPEG maximum quality` acceptable in journal's workflow? You won't see any visual difference, if you're afraid to loose quality.

Comment: @VadimR :the journal's Website says they only accept .eps or TIFF images, and their preference is .eps .  My coauthor also wants to work with .eps files.

Comment: I mean there's `EPS options` dialog window after you click `Save` in `Save As` dialog. And, *Photoshop EPS* vs TIFF is only useful if there are vector shapes and/or text in PSD file.